# Extend LVM in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. I have 3 drives on the server. SDA=1.8TB, SDB=1.8TB, SDC=6.4TB. The OS is installed on SDA. When execute a df-h command I appear to be missing some space on SDA. It's not adding up to 1.8TB. It seems the OS install did not allocate the lvm buntu--vg-ubuntu--lv to use the full amount of space. There is about 1TB missing. How do I extend the LVM and reclaim that space? or see where it's being used?

```
$ df-h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               26G  2.4M   26G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G   11G  176G   6% /
tmpfs                              126G     0  126G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  105M  805M  12% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  7.9M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb                           1.8T   77M  1.7T   1% /drives/raid10-1
/dev/sdc                           6.4T   89M  6.0T   1% /drives/raid5-1
/dev/loop0                          30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop1                          55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop2                          72M   72M     0 100% /snap/lxd/16099
tmpfs                               26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/1000


$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop1                       7:1    0   55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2                       7:2    0 71.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16099
sda                         8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  1.8T  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  200G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk /drives/raid10-1
sdc                         8:32   0  6.4T  0 disk /drives/raid5-1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Want **l**ogical **v**olumes **extend**ed? You likely want to read up on a command called `lvextend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking free space in Volume Groups using command "vgs" and if there is free space then you can try expanding Logical Volume using "lvextend" command and later when LV is extended you can continue with file system extending. Example can be here: https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/

Comment: Thanks I was struggling with where the space went and why it wasn't allocated. My final commands were. sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv and then ran sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv